# Frame stream error when using medium-sized fetchSize in Cassandra node.js driver

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-node-driver

I am having a weird issue with the Cassandra node.js driver. When I try to select data from certain partitions, I get this error.

```
Error: There was an problem while parsing streaming frame, opcode 8
    at DriverInternalError.DriverError (C:\Temp\cassandra_test\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\errors.js:14:19)
    at new DriverInternalError (C:\Temp\cassandra_test\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\errors.js:68:30)
    at Parser._transform (C:\Temp\cassandra_test\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib\streams.js:149:16)
    at Parser.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at Parser.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:307:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:293:5)
    at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:220:11)
    at Protocol.ondata (_stream_readable.js:556:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
name: 'DriverInternalError',
stack: 'Error: There was an problem while parsing streaming frame, opcode 8\n    at DriverInternalError.DriverError (C:\\Temp\\cassandra_test\\node_modules\\cassandra-driver\\lib\\errors.js:14:19)\n    at new DriverInternalError (C:\\Temp\\cassandra_test\\node_modules\\cassandra-driver\\lib\\errors.js:68:30)\n    at Parser._transform (C:\\Temp\\cassandra_test\\node_modules\\cassandra-driver\\lib\\streams.js:149:16)\n    at Parser.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)\n    at Parser.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)\n    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:307:12)\n    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:293:5)\n    at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:220:11)\n    at Protocol.ondata (_stream_readable.js:556:20)\n    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)',
message: 'There was an problem while parsing streaming frame, opcode 8',
info: 'Represents a bug inside the driver or in a Cassandra host.',
```

There is some really weird behavior here.

- It doesn't happen with smaller `fetchSize`s. E.g., I can consistently get it to error out with a fetch size of 312 or higher, but using a fetch size of 311 works every time.
- It only happens for some partition keys. So far, it appears to be affecting keys that have been recently added.
- Within a single table, the breaking point for `fetchSize` is consistent. E.g., I can run `SELECT * FROM TableX WHERE myKey = value1` or `SELECT * FROM TableX WHERE myKey = value2` and both will start to error out at a `fetchSize` of 240, say. But for `TableY`, the limit might be 284.

I'm really kind of at a loss here. I would suspect it has something to do with returning too many rows from a single partition, but I am able to get plenty of data from other partitions (e.g., a `fetchSize` of 20000 works fine on most partitions).

A simple bit of code to reproduce the issue is

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver')
var client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['node1', 'node2', 'node3'], keyspace: 'ks' });
var query = 'SELECT * FROM TableX WHERE myKey = :value';
client.eachRow(query, { value: 'someValue' }, { prepare: true, fetchSize: 500 }, function(n, row) {
    console.log(row);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

Comment: It looks like a driver bug, could you try without streaming, using the same partition keys and fetch sizes? ie: `client.execute(query, params, options, callback)`

Comment: @jorgebg Yes, just using `execute` works. I guess it's just the streaming that's breaking.

Comment: Hmm. After some more testing, I traced this to version 3.1.2 of the node.js Cassandra driver. Using 3.1.1 works, but 3.1.2 breaks every time. It doesn't look like `streams.js` is the issue, but there were a lot of changes to `connection.js`, so it might be coming from one of those.

Comment: Are u using Apache Cassandra distribution or DataStax Enterprise?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, it looks like it's the issue described in https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/NODEJS-310 . Could you confirm if you are using: DSE Search / non-vanilla Cassandra or you have query tracing enabled?

Comment: @jorgebg We're just using open source Cassandra, not DSE. I'm not using the `traceQuery` option. Might be another flag? I'm not sure what "custom payload" or "warnings" are.

Comment: I've just submitted a pull request to fix the issue in NODEJS-310 ticket, do you have a minute to try it out? ie: `npm install --save datastax/nodejs-driver#NODEJS-310`

Comment: @jorgebg Nice, seems to be working. I tried executing the same code against the released version and your patched version. The released breaks and the patched works—`fetchSize = 5000`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! Once the patch is reviewed and tested, we will release v3.1.4 containing the fix.

Comment: @jorgebg Awesome, thanks. Really cool that you were able to update it so quickly.

Comment: We've released v3.1.4 that includes this fix, update via npm. Thanks!!

Comment: @jorgebg Awesome. Thanks for the quick turnaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with OP, it looks like a bug in version 3.1.3 of the driver:

More info: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/NODEJS-310

It's now fixed in [v3.1.4 of the driver](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cassandra-driver).